# Installing C++ packages on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, c++

I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

I am trying to install the C++ package Linbox (https://linalg.org/). I am trying to install it on ubuntu using apt-get install, so I am doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install liblinbox-dev
sudo apt-get install libgivaro-dev
sudo apt-get install fflas-ffpack
```

Since givaro and fflas-ffpack are required packages for linbox. When I try to compile the example file call rank.cpp, I get the error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/linbox/field/hom.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/linbox/matrix/densematrix/blas-matrix.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/linbox/matrix/dense-matrix.h:79,
                 from /usr/include/linbox/matrix/matrixdomain/blas-matrix-domain.h:51,
                 from /usr/include/linbox/matrix/matrix-domain.h:68,
                 from /usr/include/linbox/matrix/sparsematrix/sparse-generic.h:80,
                 from /usr/include/linbox/matrix/sparse-matrix.h:70,
                 from rank.cpp:40:
/usr/include/linbox/ring/ntl/ntl-zz.h:33:10: fatal error: NTL/ZZ.h: No such file or directory
   33 | #include <NTL/ZZ.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

After I install ntl using

```
sudo apt-get install libntl-dev
```

But after attempting to compile again, I get the following error (this is just the last bit of the error as there is a lot more above):

```
rank.cpp:(.text._ZNK6Givaro5ZRingINS_7IntegerEE4readERSiRS1_[_ZNK6Givaro5ZRingINS_7IntegerEE4readERSiRS1_]+0x27): undefined reference to `Givaro::operator>>(std::istream&, Givaro::Integer&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cccUiBtG.o: in function `Givaro::ZRing<Givaro::Integer>::write(std::ostream&, Givaro::Integer const&) const':
rank.cpp:(.text._ZNK6Givaro5ZRingINS_7IntegerEE5writeERSoRKS1_[_ZNK6Givaro5ZRingINS_7IntegerEE5writeERSoRKS1_]+0x27): undefined reference to `Givaro::operator<<(std::ostream&, Givaro::Integer const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cccUiBtG.o: in function `Givaro::UnparametricOperations<Givaro::Integer>::assign(Givaro::Integer&, Givaro::Integer const&) const':
rank.cpp:(.text._ZNK6Givaro22UnparametricOperationsINS_7IntegerEE6assignERS1_RKS1_[_ZNK6Givaro22UnparametricOperationsINS_7IntegerEE6assignERS1_RKS1_]+0x27): undefined reference to `Givaro::Integer::operator=(Givaro::Integer const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cccUiBtG.o: in function `Givaro::UnparametricOperations<Givaro::Integer>::read(std::istream&, Givaro::Integer&) const':
rank.cpp:(.text._ZNK6Givaro22UnparametricOperationsINS_7IntegerEE4readERSiRS1_[_ZNK6Givaro22UnparametricOperationsINS_7IntegerEE4readERSiRS1_]+0x27): undefined reference to `Givaro::operator>>(std::istream&, Givaro::Integer&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cccUiBtG.o: in function `Givaro::UnparametricOperations<Givaro::Integer>::write(std::ostream&, Givaro::Integer const&) const':
rank.cpp:(.text._ZNK6Givaro22UnparametricOperationsINS_7IntegerEE5writeERSoRKS1_[_ZNK6Givaro22UnparametricOperationsINS_7IntegerEE5writeERSoRKS1_]+0x27): undefined reference to `Givaro::operator<<(std::ostream&, Givaro::Integer const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cccUiBtG.o: in function `void std::_Construct<Givaro::Rational>(Givaro::Rational*)':
rank.cpp:(.text._ZSt10_ConstructIN6Givaro8RationalEJEEvPT_DpOT0_[_ZSt10_ConstructIN6Givaro8RationalEJEEvPT_DpOT0_]+0x26): undefined reference to `Givaro::Neutral::zero'
/usr/bin/ld: rank.cpp:(.text._ZSt10_ConstructIN6Givaro8RationalEJEEvPT_DpOT0_[_ZSt10_ConstructIN6Givaro8RationalEJEEvPT_DpOT0_]+0x4a): undefined reference to `Givaro::Rational::Rational(Givaro::Neutral)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cccUiBtG.o: in function `void std::_Construct<Givaro::Rational, Givaro::Rational const&>(Givaro::Rational*, Givaro::Rational const&)':
rank.cpp:(.text._ZSt10_ConstructIN6Givaro8RationalEJRKS1_EEvPT_DpOT0_[_ZSt10_ConstructIN6Givaro8RationalEJRKS1_EEvPT_DpOT0_]+0x43): undefined reference to `Givaro::Rational::Rational(Givaro::Rational const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is the easiest way I can install this package along with all its required dependencies? I apologize I am not very good with installing these sorts of packages.

Comment: Where did you obtain the `rank.cpp` file? I only see a `rank.C` file in the package. How exactly are you trying to compile it?

Comment: I modified some of the rank.C file to not show some outputs and had saved it as a .cpp file. I am compiling using g++ rank.cpp -o rank

Comment: In names for files and directories, case probably makes a difference. NTL will fail if the directory is ntl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command

```
g++ rank.cpp -o rank
```

is insufficient to create an executable program - it fails to link any of the required libraries (and to set appropriate compilation flags).

The easiest way to obtain these is using the provided `pkg-config` file:

```
g++ -o rank rank.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs linbox)
```

If you are interested in what the flags / libraries are, you can execute the command directly:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs linbox
-DDISABLE_COMMENTATOR -fopenmp -fabi-version=6 -llinbox-1.6.3 -lntl -lmpfr -liml -fopenmp -lblas -llapack -lgivaro -lgmp -lgmpxx
```

Comment: Thank you! So when I ran this, I got the error:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpfr
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -liml
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Bark that means your system is still missing some build dependencies - `libmpfr-dev` and `libiml-dev`

Comment: Thank you for your help, this resolved it completely for me. In general when installing a package, I should use pkg-config to see which libraries are also dependent on it?

Comment: @Bark in many cases the software's documentation will provide a list of prerequisites - however there's often some work to translate those to Debian package names (for example, it may say `requires MPFR` which you need to figure out the corresponding `libmpfr-dev`)